# Simple DB storage using Firebase

Tags: firebase

I been trying to use Firebase to set up a simple DB to store usernames.

Right now am running a localhost page with a input field and a button to submit to Firebase.

My Firebase code is:

```
var myRootRef = new Firebase('https://myappname.firebaseio.com/');
var childRef = myRootRef.child('users');
```

Then inside my click event I do:

`childRef.push(_user);`

This works but I end up with the following structure on Firebase:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "-J1aJh8xQCgYU23m5qWc" : "sdfsd",
    "-J1aJQ1g5dw25SCGTLlq" : "ad",
    "-J1aJPZET6j7Kn8-nIZR" : "ad",
    "-J1aJg_ZchLeEVdnJnTb" : "adam",
    "-J1aJQrC2T5CfT0bNgeY" : "aaa",
    "-J1aJQTguxhvrMqcI4uU" : "dddd"
  }
}
```

When what I want is:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "user" : "sdfsd",
    "user" : "ad",
    "user" : "ad",
    "user" : "adam",
    "user" : "aaa",
    "user" : "dddd"
  }
}
```

Reading the Docs it looks like I need to use setPriority but passing a number overwrites my previous data... How does one go about setting up saving like I desire? Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean '"user1" : "sdfsd", "user2" : "ad",...'? It's not possible to have the same key "user" in an object multiple times.

Comment: Yeah User1 and User2 would work great. Something more human friendly basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want human friendly names, you'll need to manually generate them. One way to do this is to create a counter, for example, in `/lastUser`. Every time you want to create a new user, you'll increment this counter using `transaction`, and then create the user by using `set` instead of `push`.

```js
var myRootRef = new Firebase('https://myappname.firebaseio.com/');
var childRef = myRootRef.child('users');
var counterRef = myRootRef.child('lastUser');
counterRef.transaction(function(current) {
  return current + 1;
}, function(err, committed, snapshot) {
  if (!err && committed) {
    childRef.child("user" + snapshot.val()).set("userdata");
  }
});
```

For a more full fledged example check out https://gist.github.com/anantn/4323981, you can use the same approach to generate human friendly userIDs as well.

Comment: While this is still correct for my question. I needed to go with the solution I used in my own question. The reason being that the app could be launched by multiple users at the same time. So time stamped based records were actually required.